# Memory standards and Overclock

Tags: motherboard, memory

When I am looking at the memory standard specification of motherboard, almost every number except 2133 has a asterisk next to it indicating "overclock". I've never done any overclock in my life so I am kind of in over my head.

1) I am planning to buy a RAM with 3000MHZ, do I need to overclock anything to make the best of it?

2) [This motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130875) seems to be the only one without asterisks to the memory standards, or does it mean anything above 2133 is "overclocked"?

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is not overclocking. Overclocking is pushing a device over it's specified limits, so if you made the 3000MHz RAM sticks run at 4000MHz, then it would be overclocked. Motherboards will run all DDR4 RAM at 2133MHz (base speed for DDR4) to improve compatibility. To run RAM at their specified speed you would need to enable XMP (Extreme Memory Profile) in the BIOS.

To choose for RAM with your motherboard, check with the manual of your motherboard for the specific model of your RAM for compatibility.

Comment: Then what exaclty does the `(*O.C.)` (I figure O.C. stands for overclock) mean in the specification of motherboards like this one http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128836

Comment: I'm assuming it means that you need to enable XMP to achieve that speed